# How to save a boolean value into soapui property using groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have a response like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-05-03T12:55:54Z",
  "data": {
    "update_by": null,
    "create_at": "2016-05-03T12:55:54Z",
    "delete_by": null,
    "update_at": "2016-05-03T12:55:54Z",
    "create_by": null,
    "primary": true,
    "address": "email@gmail.com",
    "delete_at": null,
    "type": "public",
    "id": "c770b810-5895-88fa-aa90-88bba76678dd"
  },
  "success": true
}
```

and i use this groovy code to save some datas.
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

```
def response = context.expand( '${create_email#Response#declare namespace ns1=\'https://zenith.io/ns/20780518\'; //ns1:create_person_email_resp[1]/ns1:item[1]/ns1:response[1]}' )

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(response)

log.info result.data.id
log.info result.data.address
log.info result.data.type
log.info result.data.primary


testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("email_id", result.data.id )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("email", result.data.address )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("type", result.data.type )
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("primary", result.data.primary )
```

The data with boolean (primary) cannot be saved.
i see this error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestCasePro.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) values: [primary, false] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String) error at line: 17

How can I save the boolean value in property for primary?

Answer (score 2):

```
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("primary", result.data.primary as String)
```